# Is the 'Lifejacket' Badge a new thing?

Tags: support, badges

I earned two "Lifejacket" badges today, [not both on AD] on questions that had passed the criteria for its merit a long time ago.

[image]

Is it just a 'new' badge, now being applied retrospectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this badge and its gold version [Lifeboat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/259/lifeboat) are new badges, announced in today's blog post [Adios to Unfriendly Badges: Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/). As stated in the blog,

> We’re retroactively awarding these badges so if you’ve rescued any questions in the past, that achievement will be recognized within about 24 hours. Again, this is for all sites on the network.

Comment: Darnit - based on that, as one of those has now a +150 on the question & +100 on the answer, I just missed out on the gold Lifeboat by one downvote in its first couple of days of life. [It got 8 downvotes all-told, but idk if it ever hit -3 at any time]

Comment: @Tetsujin Our gold is going to be very hard to get - not enough people vote down and same with the up once a post is fixed.

Comment: Kudos to Tetsujin for putting in efforts. @bmike, we can definitely use more fine (+ active) folks here :)